# Using firebase Idtoken instead of custom token without compromising security

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have following use cases:

- I have cloud functions which are accessible with HTTP endpoint and they use authorization using custom token because the app is only accessible with certain IPs stored in RTDB so I have created one cloud function with will generate a custom token after signing in user using firebase client SDK and then it will create a custom token using admin SDK after checking IPs which are stored in RTDB.
- Now with every subsequent call client will send token and functions will serve the request.
- I have event listeners bound with the RTDB on a client and use file upload using client SDK  which client initialize with `firebaseApp.auth().signInWithCustomToken(custom token)`.
- On the function side I use the same sign in the method that also utilizes my firebase SDK and then I serve that request. The problem here is this sign in the method is very slow like it is taking generally more than 1 second only in sign in.

**Alternative**

Now alternative is I can use id token which can be created using `currentUser.getIdToken()` on the client side itself and it takes barely few ms to decode that token but I cannot initialize SDK with that token. so I have to use admin SDK but my IP node in RTDB is not accessed by the normal user and can only be accessed with admin SDK, so if I use ADMIN SDK with Control Access with Custom Claims and Security Rules to give admin SDK similar access that the authorized user has then IP node will not be accessible.

**Issues with id token**

Id token can be refreshed on the client side so once a client has a custom token, It can generate as many tokens it wants and that is not desirable. Apart from that validating IP everytime is not the operation that I wanted to do so with custom token I only use that in generating a custom token and then for a refreshing token but with id token, this would not be possible as the client can generate it with SDK.

Basically, I have to use firebase SDK on the client side which will need custom token(for additional authorization check) to initialize and at the same time I call the clound function from the similar app so what is the best way to implement this use case.

Comment: Your question is really hard to understanding what problem you are having.